# Power Point multiple presentations in one deck

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is it possible to have multiple defined presentations in one deck reusing multiple slide in each of the presentations.
E.g.
First slide lists:

```
Topic A
Topic B
Topic C
```

I want be able to select a presentation by-

```
Selecting Topic A will use slide 2,3,5,7,8,11 etc
Selecting Topic B will use slide 2,3,4,6,7,10,11
Selecting Topic C well you get the picture
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using Custom Shows.  On the Slide Show tab, choose Custom Slide Show, then click New in the Custom Shows dialog box that appears. That brings up the Define Custom Show dialog where you can give the show a name (say Topic A in your example) and add whatever slides you like to the custom show.

Repeat for each of the other topics. The same slide can belong to multiple custom shows.

Then add a shape or button for each of the topics, say on the first page or wherever you want to branch from. Assign a hyperlink to each of these shapes ... Insert Hyperlink, Place in this Document, Custom Shows and choose the show/Topic you want to link to. Put a check next to "Show and return" at the bottom right of the dialog box.

That should about do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have multiple PowerPoint files and want to organize them to one PowerPoint file grouped by topic? If so, we can merge your multiple PowerPoint files to one file:

On the **Home** tab of the ribbon, in the **Slides** group, click the arrow below **New Slide**, and then select **Reuse Slides**. In the **Reuse Slides** pane, click **Open a PowerPoint File** to merge files.

Then we can use the **[Zoom for PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-zoom-for-powerpoint-to-bring-your-presentation-to-life-9d6c58cd-2125-4d29-86b1-0097c7dc47d7)** feature in PowerPoint 2016 (This feature is only available for Office 365 Subscriber on Windows) to organize your sliders. When you create a Zoom in PowerPoint, you can jump to and from specific slides, sections, and portions of your presentation in an order you decide while you're presenting.

[Create Sections in PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/organize-your-powerpoint-slides-into-sections-de4bf162-e9cc-4f58-b64a-7ab09443b9f8?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fadd-or-remove-sections-in-a-powerpoint-presentation-1abac2b7-0c74-487b-bf7b-04271b5abc1b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), then go to **Insert** > **Zoom**, select **Section Zoom**. Select the section you want to use as a **Section Zoom**. Select **Insert**. Your Section Zoom will be created.